# parskip=half garbles sometimes pages

Tags: errors, parskip

I am making documents with the option parskip=half. I have observed, that I sometimes get garbled pages, where I have no explanation for. I would expect a problem inside of Tex or Latex. With some help, I could boil down the problem into this MWE. Page 2 has text and tables unreadable.[image: text and table on page 2]

I want to show this problem in order to get a solution one day. A workaround is not the question, I got already one. What could be buggy?

Ulrich

```
% !TEX TS-program = pdflatex
% !TEX encoding = UTF-8 Unicode

\documentclass[11pt,a4paper,twoside]{article}

\usepackage{kantlipsum}
%\usepackage{parskip}
\setlength{\parskip}{.5\baselineskip plus .5\baselineskip}

\begin{document}

\section{Section One}
\subsection{Subsection test}
\kant[1-3]

\begin{table}[ht]
\caption{Results of emission measurement at test conditions}
\centering
\begin{tabular}{cc}
0,03 ppb & Concentration measured at location 1  \\
1,14 ppb & Concentration measured at location 2  \\
1,14 ppb & Concentration measured at location 3  \\
1,14 ppb & Concentration measured at location 3  \\
1,14 ppb & Concentration measured at location 3  \\
1,14 ppb & Concentration measured at location 3  \\
1,14 ppb & Concentration measured at location 6  \\
1,14 ppb & Concentration measured at location 6  \\
\end{tabular}
\label{tab:testResults}         
\end{table}

\kant[4]

\begin{table}[hb]
\caption{Results of emission measurement at test conditions}
\centering
\begin{tabular}{cc}
0,03 ppb & Concentration measured at location 1  \\
1,14 ppb & Concentration measured at location 2  \\
1,14 ppb & Concentration measured at location 3  \\
1,14 ppb & Concentration measured at location 3  \\
1,14 ppb & Concentration measured at location 3  \\
1,14 ppb & Concentration measured at location 3  \\ 
1,14 ppb & Concentration measured at location 6  \\ 
1,14 ppb & Concentration measured at location 6  \\
1,14 ppb & Concentration measured at location 6  \\
1,14 ppb & Concentration measured at location 6  \\
1,14 ppb & Concentration measured at location 6  \\
1,14 ppb & Concentration measured at location 6  \\
1,14 ppb & Concentration measured at location 6  \\
\end{tabular}
\label{tab:testTabTwo}         
\end{table}


\subsection{Subsection Two}

\kant[5]
\end{document}
```

Comment: I do not know the reason for this problem, but it may be relevant that it disappears when you remove the `h` specifiert from the floats.

Comment: See https://www.latex-project.org/cgi-bin/ltxbugs2html?pr=latex/4112&category=LaTeX&responsible=anyone&state=anything&keyword=parskip&search=

Comment: @Ulrike Fischer, Thanks for the link. So this problem is known since 2010 and not solved in 2018, it seems to be a difficult one.

Comment: You could add a comment to ask if there are news...

Comment: @schtandard, I am in need for the h option, because my documents have more floats than text. I learned, I can use a minipage instead. For example:
'\begin{center}
\begin{minipage}{\textwidth}
\includegraphics[width=0.7\textwidth]{Platzhalter}
\captionof{figure}{Sample point location at test conditions}
\label{fig:MaintSamplePoint}
\end{minipage}
\end{center}'

Comment: In my experience, one is never "in need" of the `h` option. You are of course free to choose to use it, but usually using it defeats the purpose of the float environment (as you mentioned yourself, a `minipage` may be better suited). If you have so many floats, the `p` option may be useful as well. That said, have you tried the workaround mentioned in Ulrike's link?

Comment: Yes, I have tried the workaround mentioned in Ulrike's link. It works in my example, so I will use it in cases.