# Float overlaps due to low value of \textfraction?

Tags: floats, positioning, page-breaking

In some sources a low value of \textfraction=0.07 is recommmended (see https://aty.sdsu.edu/bibliog/latex/floats.html). However, if I apply these values, some of my floats (both images and tables) overlap with the text, even though there would be enough space. Why is that?

Minimal working example see below:

```
% Document class
\documentclass[ a5paper, % type of paper
                fontsize=9pt, 
                parskip=half, % distance between paragraphs shall be half a line
                usegeometry, % facilitates use of geometry package into scrbook class
                ]{scrbook}
\usepackage[english, ngerman]{babel}

\usepackage{geometry}
\newgeometry{left=5cm, right=1.6cm, top=1.1cm, bottom=1.1cm, % margins from page to body
    includeheadfoot, % header and footer are considered as part of the body, hence are placed within margins
    headsep=0.6cm, % vertical distance from top of textbody to bottom of header
    footskip=0.9cm, % vertical distance from bottom of textbody to top(?) of footer
    footnotesep=0.9cm, % vertical distance from bottom of textbody to top(?) of footnotes
}
\usepackage{showframe}

\renewcommand{\textfraction}{0.07}  % allow minimal text w. figs
\usepackage[draft]{pgf}


\begin{document}

and classified correctly. Then, the linear fit described in step three can be correctly performed (see right hand side of Fig.~\ref{fig:06_FSM_preoptim}).

\begin{figure} [htbp]
    \centering
    \begin{pgfpicture}
        \pgftext{\pgfimage[width=\textwidth,height=12.927cm]{dummy}}
    \end{pgfpicture}
    \caption{Diagram, in which the benefits of the preoptimization before the linear fit are demonstrated}
    \label{fig:06_FSM_preoptim}
\end{figure}

\section{Next section}

In contrast to ...

\end{document}
```

Result is the following: [image: Screenshot of pdf]

Comment: (i) your code contain undefined page styles, (ii) remove emty line before `\begin{figure}` (iii) welcome to tex.se!

Comment: @Zarko - During the process of copying and pasting the LaTeX code into the posting, some linebreaks appear to have gotten lost, leading to various error messages. I've taken the liberty of editing the posting to re-introduce the line breaks that had gone AWOL.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [parskip=half garbles sometimes pages](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/422384/43317). See the link in Ulrikes comment below the question there: as a workaround you can use `\vspace{\parskip}\pagebreak` before `\section{Next section}`.

Comment: See https://www.latex-project.org/cgi-bin/ltxbugs2html?pr=latex/4112

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So the issue seems to be a combination of parskip, flushbottom and a significantly underfull vbox. In this case Tex may position elements such that they overlap. This error is known since 2010, but there does not seem to be a general solution instead to manually add a \vspace{\parskip} between the float and the next section heading.

Sources:

- My question in German answered by Markus Kohm: https://komascript.de/node/2176
- Same issue: [parskip=half garbles sometimes pages](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/422384/parskip-half-garbles-sometimes-pages)
- Issue explained and solution: https://www.latex-project.org/cgi-bin/ltxbugs2html?pr=latex/4112

Answer (score 4):

I don't think the text-image overlap issue you're encountering is related -- at least not immediately -- to the directive

```
\renewcommand{\textfraction}{0.07}
```

Instead, it looks like there's a hidden conflict between what the `\geometry` directive does and what some of the other set-up processes associated with the `scrbook` class are meant to accomplish. For sure, removing the option

```
includeheadfoot
```

from the `\geometry` directive gets rid of the overlap issue.

I'm afraid that not knowing exactly what the page layout is supposed to be, I can't make other suggestions.

Comment: Thank you for pointing me into the right direction. However, I tested several things by now (among others the usegeometry option) and the figure still overlaps the text (see updated minimal working example above). 

Interestingly, if I remove parskip=half the output is as desired, that is the figure is positioned slightly to the bottom.

Do you have any more ideas?

Comment: @gebbissimo - I see you reinstated the option `includeheadfoot`. As I'm not privy to your document layout needs, I can't tell if it's essential for you to do so. Have you tried not including this option?

Comment: Thanks again for your response. The geometry is defined by the publisher by the foot including the statement includeheadfoot, so I can't just not include this option. However, I found the underlying issue to the problem, which I will post right now.